# Shell Script to change recipient name in eml file

Tags: python, shell, sed

I want to make a shell script which changes the recipient each time I run it. 
I have a eml file in which the recipient needs to be different every time.
Like I need to make a change in

To: ABC (abc1@xyz.com)

So here I want to change abc each time. Like here it is abc1 then it can be abc2 and so on till say abc100.

I'm trying to get a hand at sed but haven't able to use it fully till now.

Comment: What's you input and expected output?

Comment: What is the python connection? (You have a python tag).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `formail` (from the procmail package)

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    formail -f -I "To: abc$i@example.com" < msg.eml | sendmail -t
done
```